# Always getting null value from IWebHostEnvironment and IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor

Im trying to upload files. But the IWebHostEnvironment and IHttpContextAccessor always return null value. Here is part of the controller.

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<LS>> PostStApp(StApp stapp)
{
  var url = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
  var path = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\upload\\{stapp.ImageName}";
  var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path);
  fileStream.Write(stapp.Image, 0, stapp.Image.Length);
  fileStream.Close();
  stapp.ImageName = $"https://{url}/upload/{stapp.ImageName}";

        await _unitOfWork.StApp.Insert(stapp);
        await _unitOfWork.Save(HttpContext);

        return CreatedAtAction("GetStApp", new { id = stapp.Id }, stapp);
}
```

The url and path is always null. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Where is the code setting `_webHostEnvironment` and `_httpContextAccessor`?

Comment: Hi @Waller, Did you dependency injection the two services by constructor?

Comment: Thanks @Rena . Thats the problem. I forgot about that. After putting the DI, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure dependency injection the two services by constructor like below:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to Dependency Injection the 2 services. This works after putting in this in the controller..

```
  public SAppController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
```

Comment: And why exactly do you need to inject the http context accessor ?